# Одинаковые отступы со всех сторон. Flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть гибкий блок с тремя вложенными блоками.

```css
div{
  height: 20px;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: gray;
}
.d1 {background: red;}
.d2 {background: green;}
.d3 {background: blue;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1">Текст</div>
  <div class="d2">Длинный длинный длинный длинный текст</div>
  <div class="d3">Длинный текст</div>
</div>
```

Как сделать равные отступы со всех сторон? Все серые куски должны быть одинаковой длины, и не зависеть от длины вложенных блоков.
Этот простой вопрос поставил меня в тупик.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Склоняюсь к тому, что это костыль, но ничего лучше что-то не придумывается.

Убираем отступы по краям (`space-between` вместо `space-around`) и вставляем ещё 2 псевдоэлемента, чтобы получить полный отступ около них, а не половинный по краям:

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: gray;
}

.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
}

.d1 { background: red;   }
.d2 { background: green; }
.d3 { background: blue;  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1">Текст</div>
  <div class="d2">Длинный длинный длинный длинный текст</div>
  <div class="d3">Длинный текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это костыль конечно, но главное что работает :)

Comment: Хитро :). Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Появилось новое значение `space-evenly`, хотя браузерная поддержка [пока так себе](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) - поддерживается в Chrome 60+, FF 52+; не поддерживается в IE и Edge.

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: gray;
}

.d1 { background: red;   }
.d2 { background: green; }
.d3 { background: blue;  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1">Текст</div>
  <div class="d2">Длинный длинный длинный длинный текст</div>
  <div class="d3">Длинный текст</div>
</div>
```